# SSIS Data Flow Task takes 20 hours to complete

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a scheduled SSIS job which runs daily. The job runs a select query on a SQL 2008 R2 server and then generates a text file. Generally, the job takes less than a minute to complete but sometimes it just takes hours to complete.

Symptoms :
1. The job gets stuck at "Pre-Execute phase is beginning" for just over 10 hours.
2. Then it starts processing the output file.
3. The job then immediately gets stuck at "Rows were provided to a data flow component as input" for another 10 hours.

I don't know what needs to be changed at package level because it works fine 90% of the time. Also, I tried to find a pattern and don't see any. The data being extracted remains almost same. There is no other connection to the table during the job run.

Comment: Do you check it for blocking when it is taking a long time?

Comment: Yes, I did and there are no blockings.